# Elasticsearch build sql server index and create search query failes

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, query-string

After reading and trying several of articles and getting no result..

I want to create and elasticsearch query that returns data base results

**Example**:

**[Step 1]:**
my db is [my_db] and my table name is [my_table]
to build new index on ***localhost:9200***

```
POST /my_index/my_type/_meta 
{
    "type":"jdbc",
    "jdbc": 
    {
        "driver":"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
        "url":"jdbc:sqlserver://[my_db_ip];databaseName=[my_db]",
        "user":"sa","password":"xxxxxx",
        "sql":"SELECT * FROM [my_table]",
        "poll":"5s",
        "index": "my_index",
        "type": "my_type"     
    }
}
```

The index creation result:

```
{
   "_index": "my_index",
   "_type": "my_type",
   "_id": "_meta",
   "_version": 1,
   "created": true
}
```

**[Step 2]:**
The search query

```
POST /my_index/_search
{
    "query_string" : {
        "query" : "FreeText"
    }
}
```

The search result

```
{
   "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures....
}
```

what is wrong with my search query??

how can i create a query that returns results from [my_table] rows?

Answer (score 0):

Try the match_all query (see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-match-all-query.html) for the official documentation). This will bring you all the results of my_type.

Example:

```
POST /my_index/my_type/_search 
{
   "query": { "match_all": {} } 
}
```

If you need to search for some specific term then you must pay attention to the [mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) of your type and the [query type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-queries.html) that you'll use.

**Update**

Mappings:

From the schema of your table I understand that the below mappings for my_type would suit you well.

```
{
    "my_table" : {
        "properties" : {
            "orderid" : {"type" : "integer", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
            "ordername " : {"type" : "string" }
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that if the data are already indexed you cannot change the mappings. You must reindex your data after defining the proper mapping.

Generally I'd propose you to follow the below methodology:

1. Create your index with the index settings that you need
2. Define the mappings of your type
3. Index your data

Do not mingle all of these steps in one and avoid leaving things in luck (like default mappings).

You can use the [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-match-query.html) in order to search the data of a field on the document.

Example

```
POST /my_index/my_type/_search 
{
    "query": { 
        "match": {
           "FIELD": "TEXT"
        }
    } 
}
```

You can use the [multi-match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) in order to search the data of multiple fields of the document.

Example

```
POST /my_index/my_type/_search 
{
    "query": { 
        "multi_match": {
           "query":    "TEXT", 
           "fields": [ "field1", "field2" ]
        }
    } 
}
```

For more querying options check the official documentation on [Query DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl.html).

Comment: But where are the select result?
i want to search rows on [my_table] that contains the text "FreeText".

Comment: POST /my_index/my_type/_search
 {
  "query": { 
   "multi_match": {
      "query":    "8304869", 
      "fields": [ "OrderID" ]
   }
  } 
 }

//no results found
 {
    "took": 5,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
    }
 }

Comment: Please post your mappings in order to identify the issue. I see that you are searching for some integer and maybe you have mapped this field to string. Also, run the match_all query in order to be sure that you have actually data to search for (it will bring you all the documents of my_type in my_index).

Comment: maybe this is the problem.
i didnt created any mapping.
how can i create one? my select is [SELECT orderid,ordername FROM my_table]

Comment: Please read my updated answer with the mappings. However, I'd encourage you to read the [mapping section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) in the official documentation. It's important to understand the meaning of all these.

Comment: PUT /my_index/my_type/_mappings {...} - "error": "MapperParsingException[Root type mapping not empty after parsing! Remaining fields